# How could I speed up this SQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, query-optimization

I have this query:

```
select 
    "time_interval", 
    SUM("mv"."percent_ampl_bought") as "percent_ampl_bought", 
    SUM("mv"."percent_ampl_sold") as "percent_ampl_sold", 
    SUM("mv"."percent_ampl_transferred") as "percent_ampl_transferred", 
    SUM("mv"."amount_ampl_bought") as "amount_ampl_bought", 
    SUM("mv"."amount_ampl_sold") as "amount_ampl_sold", 
    SUM("mv"."amount_ampl_transferred") as "amount_ampl_transferred" 
from "mv_30day_daily_aggregate_buys_sells_transfers" as "mv" 
group by grouping sets ( (time_interval), () ) 
order by time_interval desc nulls last;
```

With this explain plan:

https://explain.depesz.com/s/gJXC

I have these indexes:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX mv_30day_daily_aggregate_buys_sells_transfers_primary
  ON public.mv_30day_daily_aggregate_buys_sells_transfers USING btree
  (time_interval, contract_address);

CREATE INDEX mv_30day_daily_aggregate_buys_sells_transfers_time_interval
  ON public.mv_30day_daily_aggregate_buys_sells_transfers USING btree
  (time_interval);

CREATE INDEX v_30day_daily_aggregate_buys_sells_transfers_contract_address
  ON public.mv_30day_daily_aggregate_buys_sells_transfers USING btree
  (contract_address)
```

Is it possible to further optimise this? There are only 30 time intervals for this table so I feel like I should be able to get it faster.

Comment: Can you add the table names (or table aliases) to the columns on the line: `where address = addresses.contract_address and tag_id = 3` ?

Comment: Are you joining on the `addresses` table in order to check that the address exists?  Or just to facilitate the `NOT EXISTS()` in the `address_tags`?  If it's the latter, I don't see that you need that join at all?  *(The `NOT EXISTS()` can just reference `mv.contract_address`?)*

Comment: Also, please prepend ALL columns with the table aliases. It may be obvious to you where each column comes from, but it isn't for us.

Comment: I would start by adding the index: `create index ix1 on address_tags (tag_id, address);`

Comment: I have added aliases and to simplify the query I have removed the join and updated the explain plan (the join is needed later when I limit the addresses returned to top holders but it doesn't have much impact on performance so removed it for now).

Address tags and addresses have the correct indexes.

Comment: In the case of the revised code, the explain plan shows that the reading of the data takes ~1/6 of the time and the aggregation takes ~5/6 of the time.  A hashed aggregate to 32 rows is going to take very little effort in itself, so most of the effort is likely the `SUM()`.  You could estimate that by removing all the `SUM()`s and replacing them with one `COUNT(*)` and comparing the costs.  If the hashing really is noticeable , your last remaining option is the make the index on `(time_interval, contract_address)` the clustered index, which will likely involve removing `CLUSTER` from the PK.

Comment: Or adding a covering index on the table to include ***all*** the columns in use...  `CREATE INDEX xxx ON yyy (time_interval, contract_address) INCLUDE (percent_ampl_bought, percent_ampl_sold, etc, etc...);`  Which will effectively duplicate the whole table, but in a pre-sorted order to make the aggregation as quick as possible.

Comment: Is it correct that you want to sum the percent columns? Do you not want a percent on the final totals?

Comment: @jjanes it is aggregated for every contract address per time interval, I then aggregate over it just per time interval, to reduce it to the addresses needed as the end user can specify top x number of holders. I want to sum the percent columns yes. Time interval is date and percents are numeric.

Comment: Did you try changing the clustered index, or creating an index to `INCLUDE` all the columns being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A main limitation here (at least if you have CPUs to spare) is that GROUPING SETS does not support parallel execution.  As far as I can tell, there is no fundamental reason for that, it is just that no one got around to hooking it up yet.  With only 32 groups, this should parallelize nicely if it were willing to use it.  So one thing you could do is rewrite this as two queries with a UNION ALL, so that you can get parallelization.

```
select 
    "time_interval", 
    SUM("mv"."percent_ampl_bought") as "percent_ampl_bought", 
    SUM("mv"."percent_ampl_sold") as "percent_ampl_sold", 
    SUM("mv"."percent_ampl_transferred") as "percent_ampl_transferred", 
    SUM("mv"."amount_ampl_bought") as "amount_ampl_bought", 
    SUM("mv"."amount_ampl_sold") as "amount_ampl_sold", 
    SUM("mv"."amount_ampl_transferred") as "amount_ampl_transferred" 
from "mv_30day_daily_aggregate_buys_sells_transfers" as "mv" 
group by time_interval 
union all 
select 
    NULL, 
    SUM("mv"."percent_ampl_bought") as "percent_ampl_bought", 
    SUM("mv"."percent_ampl_sold") as "percent_ampl_sold", 
    SUM("mv"."percent_ampl_transferred") as "percent_ampl_transferred", 
    SUM("mv"."amount_ampl_bought") as "amount_ampl_bought", 
    SUM("mv"."amount_ampl_sold") as "amount_ampl_sold", 
    SUM("mv"."amount_ampl_transferred") as "amount_ampl_transferred" 
from "mv_30day_daily_aggregate_buys_sells_transfers" as "mv" 
order by time_interval desc nulls last;
```

But you might as well take advantage of our knowledge that sums can be pieced together from their arbitrarily divided parts:

```
with t as (select 
    "time_interval", 
    SUM("mv"."percent_ampl_bought") as "percent_ampl_bought", 
    SUM("mv"."percent_ampl_sold") as "percent_ampl_sold", 
    SUM("mv"."percent_ampl_transferred") as "percent_ampl_transferred", 
    SUM("mv"."amount_ampl_bought") as "amount_ampl_bought", 
    SUM("mv"."amount_ampl_sold") as "amount_ampl_sold", 
    SUM("mv"."amount_ampl_transferred") as "amount_ampl_transferred" 
    from "mv_30day_daily_aggregate_buys_sells_transfers" as "mv" 
    group by time_interval 
) 
select * from t 
union all 
select NULL, sum(percent_ampl_bought), sum(percent_ampl_sold), sum(percent_ampl_transferred),sum(amount_ampl_bought), sum(amount_ampl_sold), sum(amount_ampl_transferred) from t 
order by time_interval desc nulls last;
```

With this last one, I get about a 3 fold speed over the original, but it would be more if I had more than 2 CPUs on my test box.

Also, if you change the types to double precision rather than numeric, then it would be faster yet.